# Is there a way to write Common Lisp code in DrRacket?

Tags: ide, lisp, common-lisp, racket

I've been using the DrRacket IDE to write programs and I quite like the interface, so I was wondering if there was a way to write/run Common Lisp code (not a dialect like Scheme or Racket) on it. Does any one know how to set that up?

Comment: No idea^^ But look, you have a diversity of editors for Common Lisp: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/editor-support.html Emacs and Vim of course, but also Atom with SLIMA (very good plugin), one getting good for Sublime or VSCode, a simple one for Eclipse, a Jupyter-notebook kernel, and more.

Comment: I very much doubt this is usefully possible – obviously you can just edit CL files, but all the fancy editor support & integration probably isn't going to exist and I can't see the Racket people wanting to add it.  However I don't know that's the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DrRacket supports many scheme dialectes and Algol60, which has completely different surface syntax, so there is nothing in the way of making a Common Lisp implementation in DrRacket. There isn't any implementation at this time, but I often use DrRacket to format/write CL code